# Iam fresher and dont know how to use EGOImageView inside tableviewcell

Tags: ios, egoimageview

Scrolling of my tableview is very poor. So i want to use EGOImageView. Any tutorial or any suggestion.?

Comment: Please refer following link which addresses - How to add lazy image loading to UIimageview - [How to add lazy image loading to UIimageview](http://www.ciiycode.com/0m66NqXggqex/how-to-add-lazy-image-loading-to-uiimageview)

Answer (score 1):

there are several way to load image smoothly. `EGOImageView` is one of them . first of use `EGOImageView` instead of `UIImageView` and in Nib(Xib) file drag imageview and set Class EGOImageView in identity section (Property toolbar ).

Second easiest way to load image in url Using AFNetworking class.

download This framework [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)  and only import

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

and set image url like this

```
[cell.imgUser setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data.strprofileimage]];
```

i think this is helpful to you. thanks